# During what daily/mundane activities is the Yajnopavitam to be removed?

Tags: yagnopavitam

First of all this is not a duplicate of this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21180/can-the-yajnopavitam-be-ever-removed-after-once-the-person-has-initiated/21185#21185)

I am not asking about permanent removal of the sacred thread, but in what daily activities is this to be removed ?
Is it to be removed prior to ablutions, bathing, sleeping, procreation etc ?

Also from the accepted answer in the aforementioned linked question

> He should, daily, study the Vedas and **put on his sacred thread**. He should speak the truth and control his passion. [Such conduct] leads to the attainment of emancipation.

> Usana Smriti

So I assume the sacred thread is not worn all times.

Comment: See one instance I know (not of daily activities) is after funeral rites going to the Smashana Bhumi

Comment: what do you mean by removed ? it should never be removed...

Comment: @ram - please see verse quoted from usana smriti in my question. if something is being put on that means it was removed in first place albeit temporarily

Comment: nope. even under situations when it needs to be changed, the new yagnopavitam is worn before the old one is removed. your question is better phrased as 'when should it be changed' if that's what ur looking for. your assumption that it is not worn at all times is incorrect. the translation is probably incorrect. the thread has different positions for different rituals. maybe they meant the deva-ritual position as 'wearing it'

Comment: @ram - please post your comments as an answer with scripture reference to thread being worn in different position for different rituals. Is it also different positions for different daily activities ?

Comment: yes. on left shoulder for deva karyam, on right shoulder for pitru karyam, on both shoulders for manushya karyam, on right ear during nature calls.